# Laravel check if user model implements email verification

Tags: laravel

**I want to check if email verification in Laravel was enabled**. The feature can be enabled by [implementing the `MustVerifyEmail` interface on the user model](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification#model-preparation).

But what is a proper Laravel way to check if this feature was enabled?

Background: I want to create a command line user creation command that also sends an email verification link, but only if that feature is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method

```php
public function isMustVerifyEmail():bool
{
  return ($this instanceof MustVerifyEmail);
}
```

you can use like bellow

```
$check=$user->isMustVerifyEmail();
dd($check);
```

Comment: This one is great, as it can be reused more often and more beautiful!

Comment: Ckecking the instance of MustVerifyEmail only guarantees the implementation of the Interface, but if you comment out in fortify config that feature, that code will return that implementation is correct but feature is not enabled, probably the best solution will be check both, implementation of the contract and configuration of feature.

Answer (score 2):

> instanceof is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an
> instantiated object of a certain class.

So we use `instanceof` to check if `User` class implements the `MustVerifyEmail` interface:

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

if ($userObject instanceof MustVerifyEmail) {
    // Do what you want here
}
```

Comment: I've edited your answer, as the use statement was missing. without that the if silently never returns true, which is quite error-prone. I'd prefer the solution from dilo instead. Thanks for sharing though!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using fortify, which is almost secure.

I think that the correct way of check if email verification is enabled is checking Fortify config.

```
'features' => [
       
        Features::emailVerification(),
```

And you can check that with this line of code

```
in_array('email-verification',config('fortify.features'), true) ? 'email verification is enabled' : 'not enabled';
```

Comment: I was also thinking about that. So I am not sure which check is better. The generic interface check or the fortify check. I think the fortify feature just add the routes to **handle** the reset but the **verification** itself seems to be a core feature. So checking the fortify config would not be enough in this case? I am not sure.

Comment: Probably  to be sure you should implement both and check if the user object is an instance of MustVerifyEmail  and  the config is enabled

Comment: Fron Laravel doc:  Laravel Fortify is a frontend agnostic authentication backend implementation for Laravel. Fortify registers the routes and controllers needed to implement all of Laravel's authentication features, including login, registration, password reset, email verification, and more ... Which means that if you are not overrriding all this frontend logic fortify plays a fundamental role in auth system.